# Can't Reference Collection View Cell Outlets in View Controller

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

My app contains a static Collection View inside of a standard UIView. I need to let elements of the UIView talk to elements in the UICollectionView. The issue here is that when I go through suggested methods to reference one of the classes to the other, the value of the UI Element returns nil. Any ideas as to how this can be prevented? I’ve included an example below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
let cellIds = ["Purple Cell","Green Cell","Blue Cell","Red Cell"]
let cellSizes = Array(repeatElement(CGSize(width: 170, height: 80), count: 4))
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     }

@IBOutlet weak var wowNiceOutlet: UILabel!

 }
 class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     @IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!
     @IBAction func myButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
         myButton.setTitle("eat UICollectionView", for: .normal)
         let theViewControl = ViewController()
         **theViewControl.wowNiceOutlet.text = "wow nice"** //This line returns nil, causing an error.
     }

 }
```

Thank you! Let me know if you have any questions!

Updated code according to Sh_Khan:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
let cellIds = ["Purple Cell","Green Cell","Blue Cell","Red Cell"]
let cellSizes = Array(repeatElement(CGSize(width: 170, height: 80), count: 4))
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

var thisString = "nice string"
   //Theoretically thisString would be changed by a Stepper and upon doing that 
   //would be changing visual properties of the, in this case, label.
@IBOutlet weak var wowNiceOutlet: UILabel!

}
 class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
weak var parentVC:ViewController?
@IBOutlet var greenLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func myButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    myButton.setTitle("eat UICollectionView", for: .normal)

    parentVC?.wowNiceOutlet.text = "wow nice"
}

 }
  extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection 
  section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellIds.count

}
func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
  indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
  cellIds[indexPath.item], for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell // Get cell
    cell.parentVC = self
    cell.greenLabel.text = thisString
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell( withReuseIdentifier: 
 cellIds[indexPath.item], for: indexPath)

}

 }
 extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 
 collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return cellSizes[indexPath.item]

}

 }
  extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt 
  indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(cellIds[indexPath.row]);


}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this var inside the CollectionView cell subclass

```
weak var parentVC:ViewController?
```

Then set it inside `cellForItemAt`

```
cell.parentVC = self
```

After that use it like this

```
parentVC?.wowNiceOutlet.text = "wow nice"
```

---

The reason of the crash is that the outlet `wowNiceOutlet` is nil

```
let theViewControl = ViewController()
theViewControl.wowNiceOutlet.text = "wow nice"
```

as you load the vc programmatically not from storyborad.instantiate plus it's another instance

---

You return another instance of cell other than the one you set the delegate to

```
func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
  indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
  cellIds[indexPath.item], for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell // Get cell
    cell.parentVC = self

    cell.someLabel.text = "anyvalue" // <<< edit here 

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful answer. The issue I had trying this is that the label is not changing when the button is pressed. It's not returning an error thanks to the optionals, but I am assuming that the Label is still returning nil or something like that. Any suggestions?

Comment: pinging you because I forgot to in the above message, sorry.

Comment: can you share your latest update according to this answer

Comment: Do you register all the cells with ids **cellIds[indexPath.item]** as you cast them all to the same type **MyCollectionViewCell**  you may need only once register cell identifier and use it with  **dequeueCell** method ,  no need to make an array for that

Comment: Holy crap! Your edit worked. Thank you so much!! Can't wait to apply this to the project I needed this for!!

Comment: I'm sorry to continue bothering you about this, but how would I also go the other way. That is, changing properties of outlets in CollectionViewCells by triggers in the ViewController. Thanks!

Comment: create outlets inside the cell custom class , and access them like in edited answer say it's a label named **someLabel**

Comment: The application crashes immediately when running this build. The "updated" code in my post should be updated with your suggested changes by the time you read this so you can inspect. Thank you again for your continued help.

Comment: What crash , did you changed **return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell( withReuseIdentifier: 
 cellIds[indexPath.item], for: indexPath)** to **return cell**

Comment: Yes, this was changed when you suggested it unless I was supposed to make the same change elsewhere which I don't believe is the case.

Comment: what the crash says post it's log

Comment: You want the full Simulator crash log? in ~/Library/Log/CoreSimulator?

Comment: please share a demo for your problem and i'll look atm it when i sit in mac may be with github

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `let theViewControl = ViewController()` which is not the same `ViewController` you had before. You have to pass it from your original `ViewController` to the cell.